# General solutions for bezout's identity case when integers take exponential form

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do you go about finding the integer solutions for something like that? :
$$a^bx + c^dy$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers and $a$ is **odd** and $c$ is **even**

Using bezouts idenity we know that there exists solutions for:
$$a^bx + c^dy = gcd(a^b, c^d)$$
and since $a^b, c^d$ share no common factors
$$a^bx + c^dy =1$$

The problem is, how do you apply Extended Euclidean algorithm on $a^b, c^d$
(Obviously it's so easy to if you plug some values in, but I am trying to find a general solution)

I even tried to find one solution just by playing around with the equation but I doubt it works:

$$a^b(\frac {c^d + 1} {a^b}) + c^d(-1) = 1$$

Since $c$ is **even** then $c^d$ is **even** then $(c^d + 1)$ is **odd**

The only thing left is to check the divisblity

Since $a$ is **odd** then $a^d$ is odd

But Of, course this entire solution is wrong since $(c^d + 1)$ is not necessarily divisible by $a^d$ but you get idea. I need a general solution like the one I provided.

Btw, I am not asking for a solution, some hint would be more than enough except if the equation I provided is unsolvable, In this can case plz tell me so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you just write $r=a^b$ and $s=c^d$ and solve $rx+sy=1$ by the Euclidean algorithm? Then $r$ is odd, and $s$ is even.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde then $r = 2k_1 - 1$ and $s = 2k_2$ right?

Comment: @Ditrich Can I have another hint?

Comment: There is no closed form solution for general $\,a,b,c,d,\,$ but you can optimize the computation by using Hensel / Newton methods, e.g. assuming $(a,c)=1$ we have $\,x \equiv (a^{-1})^b\pmod{\!c^d}$ which can be computed by Hensel lifitng $\, a^{-1}\pmod{\! c}\,$ up to $\!\bmod c^d\,$ by Newton iteration, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13190/242)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque that's what I am talking about. you got my point. I can have this marked as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^b x + c^d y = 1$  has no *closed form* solution for general (symbolic) integers $\,a,b,c,d,\,$ but we can optimize solution computation by using Hensel / Newton methods, e.g. assuming as you do that $(a,c)=1$ we have $\,x \equiv (a^{-1})^b\pmod{\!c^d}$ which can be computed very efficiently by Hensel lifting the inverse $\, a^{-1}\pmod{\! c}\,$ up to $\!\bmod c^d\,$ by Newton iteration, e.g. see the worked examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13190/242) and in its linked posts.

[comment promoted to answer per OP request]